# dplyr combining count and filter : how to easily have correct column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr package to test "french" condition (true or false).

```
library(dplyr)
data <- c("french", "french", "french", "german","german", "italian", "italien")
data <- as.data.frame(data)
french<- data %>%
count(data == "french")
french
```

Here are my result:

```
data == "french"    n
           FALSE    4
            TRUE    3
```

Is there an easy way to have a correct first column name without renaming it in a second pipe?

```
           french   n
           FALSE    4
            TRUE    3
```

Comment: @Jimbou Your tip is great! You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the name within the count

```
data %>%
count(french = data == "french")
french   n
FALSE    4
TRUE     3
```